# laravel 5.5 built in authenticate feature database query location

Tags: database, laravel, authentication

i am using laravel in windows OS, with MySql as the database, and am trying to connect my web application's login to laravel default login/registration. the default query that runs in laravel on login is `select * from users where email="something"` i want to know where this query is located in order to modify it according to my preferred table format. any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: if u want to understand full authentication look this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuyouEHghac&list=PLe30vg_FG4OTO7KbQ6TByyY99AiSw1MDS

Comment: Please follow this documents (i.e https://sujipthapa.co/blog/laravel-v55-login-register-with-username-or-email)

Comment: i have followed that blog before and it was very helpful but i need to connect my own view and database to the code that they show within that code. thats where i am stuck. i have my view connected, but the default query tries to access `user table`. i need to change it to access `student table`. any help regarding that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is located in the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait via the `attemptLogin` method:

```
/**
 * Attempt to log the user into the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

The actual implementation is done with guards via the `attempt` method:

```
public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false)
```

See the `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard` for an example:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L347